# Android Studio navigation graph visualization export

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-navigation-editor

I want to use the Navigation graph diagram in the project wiki.
For that, I'm trying to find a way to export the Navigation graph visualization from
Navigation Editor in Android Studio.
Maybe is there a way to export it in PNG image, Vector or PDF format? Just a screenshot doesn't work for big graphs.
It seems Android Studio doesn't have it out of the box.

[image]

Comment: I found the issue in the Google tracker about it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129094328
it's not implemented yet.
But maybe some plugin exists..

Answer (score 0):

Tried to find any kind of similar plugins, unfortunately found none. Your problem seems similar to [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/n16j64/is_there_a_way_to_export_the_navigation_graph_as/). Unfortunately there probably isn't an easy way to achieve that currently.